# dynamically allocating a vector

Tags: c++, vector

is it possible to dynamically allocate a vector without specifying its Type ?

im creating a container class which should support all the numeric types
it must creat a container vector which type will be specified later when the first number is pushed into it .

first of all is this code correct ?

```
private :
        vector<int> stk ;

public :
    template <typename Typ> 
    void push (Typ input) 
    {
        vector<Typ> temp ;
                    stk = temp ;
    }
```

second : i somehow need to dynamically allocate the "stk" vector without specifying the type .

Comment: If you want `stk` to be any type make the class a template.

Comment: All templates must be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Also what does the method `push` do? Other than creating an empty vector and copying it to `stk`. The `input` isn't even used.

Comment: @BarışUşaklı : tx for the answer . but the code is just an example(yeah thats why the push method isnt doing anything :) ) . my real problem as i said was dynamicaly allocating stl containers ( in this case a vector ) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is C++ code, then templates are *specialized* at **compile time**. You cannot *delay* the allocation of a vector -- or any other template class instance -- to runtime.

A workaround would be to customize your own numeric class hierarchy with base class, say `CNumeric`, and allocate a vector of `CNumeric*`. Then the vector can accommodate any numeric type in your own class hierarchy. But of course, this workaround can be *very* inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explained the problem correctly or you haven't understood what you really need.

If I understand correctly this is what you are looking for.

```
template<typename Typ>
class A {
private :
        vector<Typ> stk ;

public :

    void push (Typ input) 
    {

         stk.push_back(input) ;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't need to change the type of things at runtime (and you can't in C++). Typically you want to change the design of your program.

If you really want to do this, you could use a union type that can hold one of a different number of things like here:

```
union A {
  int i;
  float f;
  double d;
};
```

and then store a vector of A.

Comment: I believe you need to store somewhere the actual types of elements, and every time you access the value of a union object, you need to switch through the type to decide which field to use.

Comment: I think the compiler just allocates enough space for the largest of the contained types.  Then you need to take care yourself.  So a way to produce garbage on the screen would be: A a; a.i = 1; std::cout << a.f;

Comment: That's the point. It could be messy when you access the elements -- you need to switch through the type with quite a piece of code to extract the desired value.